# Mujoco XML Error: unknown plugin when running simulate building with source code

Tags: mujoco, acme-deepmind

I installed mujoco from source code with cmake

`mkdir build & cd build`

`cmake ..`

`make .`

and edited the `.bashrc`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/xxx/Downloads/mujoco-main/build/bin`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia`

`export PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH"`

I can successfully run

`cd build/bin`

`.simulate ../model/humanoid_model.xml`

but any model with `plugin` can't be loaded.

such as `bowl.xml` and `cable.xml`

`XML Error: unknown plugin 'mujoco.elasticity.cable' Element 'plugin', line 20`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `cp lib/lib*.dylib bin/mujoco_plugin/` from the `build` directory?
Thanks!